# WordPress's "Text" Format

Tags: hooks, wysiwyg, text

When using self-hosted WordPress, you have the option of writing in "Visual" or "Text" mode.

[image: visual and text tabs in WordPress editor]

Assuming there's no plugins installed,

1. Is this "Text" format a well defined standard or pseudo standard? (like markdown, textile, etc.)
2. Is there a single place in a plugin-less `3.5.1` WordPress where this text is converted into HTML?
3. If the answer to number 2 is "No", how is this text converted into html?

Comment: 1. It's a psuedo standard. It will tolerate HTML but also will auto-generate `<p>` tags. It sometimes removes excess whitespace (I find this to be inconsistent, and based on how many trips to the visual editor one makes). More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text its just plain text, just as its saved in your db.

Wordpress changes line breaks with paragraphs with the function [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), through the filter `the_content` and `the_excerpt`.

If you need to remove the `wpautop` behavior, you can remove the filter by doing this in your theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

And maybe adding your own customized function:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_custom_format' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'my_custom_format' );

function my_custom_format ($text) {
  // do something with $text
  return $text;
}
```